# How can an organization control when or when not an update for an app is installed in their Android smartphones?

Tags: updates, security, application-autoupdate

Imagine an organization that have a legitimate fear to automatic updates. That organization thinks that an automatic update may break a business use case. For example, when the VPN client is update the users are no longer able to connect to the VPN. By automatic I mean installing the app without the organization participation and without the organization being able to test the update in advance.

**How can an organization control when and when not an app update in installed in an Android smartphone or device?**

As long as I know, if you install an app using the Play Store, the organization cannot control the updates if the user enables "automatic updates".

If the organization install the app using the APK, the application is not updated automatically but in the future the organization has to update manually the app and also if you install the app using the APK the app is not installed as "device manager" and the app can be uninstalled by the user (think in a security app like a MDM agent).

The organization uses an MDM (Airwatch) but it does not allow to control the update of Play Store installed apps.

Comment: What is device manager here? Are you talking about device administrator or device owner here?

Comment: I'm talking about a device administrator that needs to control in a centralized way what updates should be installed and when. The device propietary is the organization.

Comment: But an app (whether installed from market or sideloaded) can be made a device administrator or even a device owner. I have several of sideloaded APKs which are device administrators. Furthermore, no app from Play Store would end up installing as device administrator. Just like a sideloaded one, user's discretion is always required, so the difference between the two installation for this part seems none.

Comment: @FireLord Are you saying that you can install an app as device administrator (and avoid that the user is able to uninstall it) using the APK and not using the Play Store?

Comment: No, I attempted to address "if you install the app using the APK the app is not installed as "device manager" and the app can be uninstalled by the user" - all I'm saying is a user always  has to decide whether to make the app a device administrator or not and an app can be made a device administrator regardless of its source of installation, be it a sideload or from Play Store.

Comment: Have  a look at this [Android for work](https://www.google.com/work/android/)